# Script only sends email to last person in the list

Tags: google-apps-script

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 72; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:K73
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1];
    var name = row[4];
    var subject = 'Discovery High School Lunar New Year Volunteering';
    var message = "Good Evening " + name + "," + '\n'+ " " + '\n'
                      + "This is a reminder about High School Lunar New Years Festival." + '\n' 
                      + " " + '\n'
                      + "The event is this ." + '\n'
                      + "We also have setup after school on " + '\n'
                      + " " + '\n'
                      + "More information about shifts and jobs will be emailed out soon. Please stay updated and if you have questions, reply to this email or ask your officers." + '\n'
                      + " " + '\n'
                      + "Thank you for your help." + '\n'
  }
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
```

The email is only being sent to the last person in the list and I am not sure why. I am assuming it is something to do with my data range, but I am not very experienced in coding. If anyone could help that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 72; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:K73
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 11);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1];
    var name = row[4];
    var subject = 'Discovery High School Lunar New Year Volunteering';
    var message = "Good Evening " + name + "," + '\n'+ " " + '\n'
    + "This is a reminder about High School Lunar New Years Festival." + '\n' 
    + " " + '\n'
    + "The event is this ." + '\n'
    + "We also have setup after school on " + '\n'
    + " " + '\n'
    + "More information about shifts and jobs will be emailed out soon. Please stay updated and if you have questions, reply to this email or ask your officers." + '\n'
    + " " + '\n'
    + "Thank you for your help." + '\n'
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Must have been the range definition.

Comment: No. it was probably the position of the MailApp.sendEmail() command.  It wasn't in the loop.